# Vue Axios Mixin global method type undefined

Tags: vue.js, methods, axios, global, mixins

I am struggling with a global Vue mixin method that I want to be able to use in every component, so that I don't have to repeat the same method in all of those components.

AxiosMixin.js :

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    methods: {
        getAllUsers (){
            axios.get('/user/')
            .then(response => {
                return response.data.resources
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                window.console.log(errors)
                return
              })
        }
    }
}
```

Main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'
import crytojs from 'crypto-js'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
import mixin from './AxiosMixin'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    getAllUsers: mixin.getAllUsers
  }
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  axios,
  vuetify,
  crytojs,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In a component:

```
  created () {        
        const users = this.getAllUsers();
        users.forEach((user) => {
            this.allUsers.push({
                userid: user.u_id, 
                userinfo: user.u_first_name+" "+user.u_last_name+" ("+user.u_telephone+")",
            });
        });
    }
```

But this doesn't work. I am getting the error: Method "getAllUsers" has type "undefined" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?

I've tried to change my code in my main.js to: getAllUsers: () => mixin.getAllUsers() , but this results in the error: TypeError: *AxiosMixin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12*_.default.getAllUsers is not a function

I've already searched all over older questions but I was unable to resolve my problem. I've also read the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in

```js
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    getAllUsers: mixin.getAllUsers
  }
})
```

Change `getAllUsers: mixin.getAllUsers` into `getAllUsers: mixin.methods.getAllUsers`

But your `AxiosMixin.js` already contains mixin object in the format Vue expects so you can replace all the above code with just `Vue.mixin(mixin)`

---

There is also another problem - your `getAllUsers` is not returning anything.
Change `axios.get('/user/')...` into `return axios.get('/user/')...` so your function is returning a promis (of users)

Then use it like this:

```js
created () {        
   this.getAllUsers().then(users => ...do something with users...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed my code, but know I get the following error: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

I would assume my component doesn't understand what "this.getAllUsers()" is?